# Axios-React native PUT request

Tags: javascript, django, react-native, django-rest-framework, axios

I want to send a put request to modify the title of a file, but i keep getting 400 bad request error, i m not sure on how to formulate my request so it gets accepted.
this is the request :

```js
const onPressSaveName=()=>{
  handleEditedItem(fileTitle);
  const modefiedFile=new FormData();
  modefiedFile.append('label',label)
  modefiedFile.append('file', {
    uri: fileUri
     });
  modefiedFile.append('title',inputText)
  
  const headers={
    Accept:'application/json',
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    }
   const json=JSON.stringify(modefiedFile);
   axios
   .put(`http://192.168.1.17:8000/File/${key}/`,json,{headers:headers})
   .then((response)=> {response.json()})
   .then((error)=>{console.log(error)})       
          
  setModal(false)
}
```

this is my django backend View :

```js
elif request.method =='PUT':
        serializer=Fileserializers(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
           serializer.save()
           return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors,status=404)
```

Answer (score 0):

to help people facing the same mistake just make sure you have the right content-type and the right way to send the file in my case this modification worked:

```js
 modefiedFile.append('file', {
    uri:  fileUri,
    name: fileTitle,
    type: 'file/pdf'})
  modefiedFile.append('title',inputText)
  
  const headers={
    Accept:'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
```